# Show ProgessDialog on Button Click

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show `ProgressDialog` in `OnClick()` method in my `Activity`. I am doing like the following, but there an error. What can be the fix?

---

```
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846):    at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:561)
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846):    at com.wamiq.test_layout.ComposeMessage$4.onClick(ComposeMessage.java:237)
04-24 10:52:46.241: E/AndroidRuntime(21846):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
```

---

```
bSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (etTo.getText().toString().compareTo("") == 0)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "no sender specified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            progress.setTitle("Sending Mail");
            progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            progress.show();

            int flag = sendMail(etTo.getText().toString(), etCc.getText()
                    .toString(), etBcc.getText().toString(), etSubject
                    .getText().toString(), etMessage.getText()
                    .toString(), etSign.getText().toString(), attachlst);
            // To dismiss the dialog
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    } 
});
```

Comment: And what is the error? Also I can see that you are dismissing the `dialog` soon after showing it.

Comment: use async task for that dude

Comment: @Digvesh What do I need to do for it? Can u please elaborate..?

Comment: chack ans of grlshu its perfect for your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `progress.dismiss();` in your else part, because as you `show()` your dialog and after that directly you are dismissing it ,So as your dialog will be shown at the same time it will be dismissed and you won't get idea of it.

So i would suggest you to use the `AsyncTask` to show and remove your dialog as below:

```
class progressdialog extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityname.this);
        progress.setTitle("Sending Mail");
                    progress.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                  progress.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          int flag = sendMail(etTo.getText().toString(), etCc.getText()
                .toString(), etBcc.getText().toString(), etSubject
                .getText().toString(), etMessage.getText()
                .toString(), etSign.getText().toString(), attachlst);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
                 progress.dismiss();
          }
   }
```

Comment: he still have the sendMail who knows whats in there maybe a long term processing..

Comment: There is a function call between show and dismiss which takes time to complete...so I wanted to add a dialog to show a message like "Please Wait"...
Is there another way?

Comment: yes there is, you can use asynctask as said by one user above

Comment: @GrlsHu I did as you said... and now i am getting the following error... 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()'......I am sending mail inside this function sendMail() using JavaMail API where I need to use Java Handler

Comment: @GrlsHu...Thanks ..I was showing Toast there....Now its working fine and perfect...thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this from

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

because `getApplicationContext()` is a `Context` of your `Application` while `YourActivityName.this` is a `Context` of your `particular class or Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

At ProgressDialog initialization replace

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

to :

```
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.progressdialogpractice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button a =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.progressdialogpractice", "com.example.progressdialogpractice.SubActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);

}});

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

}
```

SubActivity.java

```
package com.example.progressdialogpractice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SubActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Handler UIhandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
UIhandler = new Handler();
setContentView(R.layout.sub);
new LoginProgressTask().execute(1);

}

class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {
 @Override
 protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer...a) {
   try {
     Thread.sleep(4000);  // Do your real work here
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return Boolean.TRUE;   // Return your real result here
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
 UIhandler.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show( SubActivity.this,"wait","downloading");
           }
       });
 }
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
   // result is the value returned from doInBackground

 UIhandler.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
     progressDialog.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(SubActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
       });
 }
}   
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

sub.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fuck you dipshit" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

user activity context in place of application context

```
wrong :ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext()); 
 correct  :ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(ActvityName.this);
```